# Jenkins - Build Vaadin Web Application takes forever

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, vaadin

My goal is to establish a Continuous Integration (IntelliJ IDEA -> github -> jenkins -> tomcat), but the process "Build Vaadin Web Application" won't end (see below). This process is implicitly called from my maven build and only ends when I kill the server (btw: the server has a limit of 500mb ram).

[image: Endless Build]

The maven goal in jenkins is "clean package". The war-file will be deployed through another jenkins plugin, but jenkins is not even getting that far.

The build-part of my pom looks as follows (it is from an archetype and I don't really understand this part yet):

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <!--vaadin-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- As we are doing "inplace" GWT compilation, ensure the widgetset -->
            <!-- directory is cleaned properly -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                    <!-- <runTarget>mobilemail</runTarget> -->
                    <!-- We are doing "inplace" but into subdir VAADIN/widgetsets. This
                        way compatible with Vaadin eclipse plugin. -->
                    <webappDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets
                    </webappDirectory>
                    <hostedWebapp>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets
                    </hostedWebapp>
                    <noServer>true</noServer>
                    <!-- Remove draftCompile when project is ready -->
                    <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                    <compileReport>true</compileReport>
                    <style>OBF</style>
                    <strict>true</strict>
                    <runTarget>http://localhost:8080/</runTarget>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- if you don't specify any modules, the plugin will find them -->
                            <!-- <modules> <module>com.vaadin.demo.mobilemail.gwt.ColorPickerWidgetSet</module>
                                </modules> -->
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--<plugin>-->
                <!--<groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>-->
                <!--<artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
            <!--</plugin>-->
            <!--vaadin end-->
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--vaadin-->
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            vaadin-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [7.0.0.beta3,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>resources</goal>
                                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!--vaadin end-->
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

The automatically generated AppWidgetSet looks like this:

```
<module>
    <inherits name="com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet"/>
</module>
```

The web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Vaadin Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
        <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>Vaadin UI to display</description>
            <param-name>UI</param-name>
            <param-value>de.bahr.dhbw.logframe.UI.NavigatorUI</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <description>Application widgetset</description>
            <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
            <param-value>de.bahr.dhbw.logframe.AppWidgetSet</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Are there any guides on using Vaadin with Jenkins? Can you help me to get this setup running? Thanks in advance!

(Also asked at https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/8523481.)

Comment: It is most likely swapping to death.  Your JVM options are not adjusted for your virtual machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Thorbjørn pointed out the issue was due to the server's capacity.

The 1st servers ram limit was 512 mb and no swap space (the hoster doesn't provide swap initially). Increasing the swap space lead to the same results. Therefore I picked another server with 1 gb ram and no swap. In that case I was confronted with a "maven failed with status 137", that told me (through google) to use swap.

And that did it: At least 1 gb ram and some swap (in my case 4 gb). The compilation of vaadin widgetsets seems quite heavy.

Comment: 6 years later and still this is the case!